# How to get withRouter to pass match params to component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I want to access the match params on the navigation on my app, I'm using `react` and `react-router-dom`. Here is a code snipped for simple example I made, as you can see on the Topics component I get the correct match at component level but not in the nav bar, I do get the correct url path in the location prop so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.

[This would be the working snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/yk33z2jn6z), since I couldn't add `react-router-dom` to the stack overflow snippet.

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const BasicExample = (props) =>
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Nav/>
      <hr />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
    </div>
  </Router>;


const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
);

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
);

const Navigation = (props) => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
    </li>
    <li>{`match prop -> ${JSON.stringify(props.match)}`}</li>
    <li>{`location prop -> ${JSON.stringify(props.location)}`}</li>
  </ul>
);

const Nav =  withRouter(Navigation);

const Topic = ({ match, location }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
    <li>{`match prop -> ${JSON.stringify(match)}`}</li>
    <li>{`location prop -> ${JSON.stringify(location)}`}</li>
  </div>
);

const Topics = ({ match, location, history }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <li>{`match prop -> ${JSON.stringify(match)}`}</li>
    <li>{`location prop -> ${JSON.stringify(location)}`}</li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
          Rendering with React
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
          Components
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
          Props v. State
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic} />
    <Route
      exact
      path={match.url}
      render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
    />
  </div>
);


ReactDOM.render(<BasicExample />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For detecting `:topicId` in `<Nav>` use [matchPath](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/matchPath.md) imported from `react-router`:

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router'

matchPath(location.pathname, { 
  path:'/topics/:topicId',
  exact: true,
  strict: false
}})
```

Comment: I see, I thought it was information passed down from the `<Router />`. You wouldn't happen to know how to do what I want to do, wouldn't you? :)

Comment: I think I dont understand... You have enought information in props.location, or what exactly are you looking for in the props.match? (which is exactly how it should be)

Comment: I wanted the `:topicId` param from the `<Topic />` component to be accessible from the navigation bar to add items to the navigation in relation to the existence of certain params. For example, I use database id in the url which I can't discern if they are from one database or another unless I have the param name.

Comment: Thank you kind stranger. That solved my problem. I thought `matchPath` did something else.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little outdated now. Can be achieved with `react-router-dom` by simply doing something like:

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

console.log(props.match.params);
```

Don't forget to wrap the component inside `withRouter`

```
export default withRouter(YourComponent);
```

`props.match.params` will return an object with all the params.